# What quotients of polynomial quotient rings are projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am trying to learn about projective modules. I.e. modules from which any homomorphism can be factored through a surjection.

To do this, I'm considering my favorite ring, which is just messy enough, $R=\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial. So now, I'm trying to figure out necessary and sufficient conditions for a quotient ring, say $P=R/(q(x))$ to be projective (i.e. let's assume it is principal).

Now it seems to me, I have an extreme, where I know $P$ to be projective. Namely, if I take $q(x)=x$ then $P\cong \mathbb{F}$ which should be projective. However, I'm not sure where to head from here?

I was thinking one could perhaps use the CRT to decompose $R$ and get some further insight comparing it with a decomposition for $q$, but I'm quite frankly stuck. How do I characterize the quotients that are projective?

To be clear, I'm considering $R=\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$-modules.

Comment: Not necessarily embedded.

Comment: Basically, $P$ is projective if for any two other $R$-modules $M_1,M_2$ and any surjective homom $\pi :M_1 \to M_2$ and any homom $\phi: P\to M_2$ there exists homom $\phi'$ such that $\phi=\pi \phi'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I\lhd F[x]$ such that $F[x]/I$ is a projective $F[x]$ module and $I$ is nontrivial, then the exact sequence 
$$
0\to I\to F[x]\to F[x]/I\to 0
$$ splits.

But that would mean $F[x]\cong I\oplus F[x]/I$, which is not possible, because $I$ intersects all other nontrivial ideals nontrivially. So, the only possibilities for $I$ are $\{0\}$ and $F[x]$.

---

*After you said that you want to use ideals of $R=F[x]/(p(x))$ module*.

That depends heavily on $p(x)$. For example if the factorization of $p(x)$ is squarefree, then *all* modules over $R$ are projective.

The logic from above still stands though: If $I\lhd R$ is an ideal such that $R/I$ is projective, then $I$ is a summand of $R$. Conversely, every summand is the kernel of a projective quotient.

You can compute all summands of $F[x]/(p(x))$ by factoring $p(x)$ into powers of irreducible elements.

For example, if $R=F[x]/(x^n)$, then no proper ideals are projective, because there are no summands.

On the other hand, $\mathbb Q[x]/(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^3$ and has $6$ nontrivial ideals, all of which are summands.

Comment: I realize I wasn't entirely clear and only mentioned sloppily that the underlying ring isn't $\mathbb{F}[x]$. How would the situation change for the ring in the question?

Comment: OK I'm really sorry for pestering you here but the question quite clearly says that I'm considering $R/(q(x))=(\mathbb{F}/(p(x))/(q(x))$. I'm guessing however the same logic still applies

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I tend to get sloppy with equivalence classes moving down the quotients...

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think I know where to look now for the details. However, if it doesn't bother you too much, would you be able to explain/reference the part about being $p$ squarefree implying every $R$-module being projective?

Comment: If $p(x)$ is squarefree, it's a semiprime ideal, and that means $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a semisimple artinian ring. All modules over a semisimple ring are projective and injective.  When it has factors with higher multiplicity, it's no longer semisimple, but it's still quasi-Frobenius. The projectives and the injectives coincide, but then some modules are niether projective nor injective.